# Lebesgue measure under diffeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In his book *Measure and Integration Theory* Bauer proves the following theorem:

[image]

Here $\text{GL}(d,\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all invertible linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\lambda^d$ denotes the Lebesgue-Borel measure on the Borel sets $\mathcal{B}^d$, and $T(\lambda^d)$ is the image measure defined by $T(\lambda^d)(A):=\lambda^d(T^{-1}(A))$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}^d$.

Bauer then makes the following remark:

[image]

Am not sure how to interpret equation $(8.16)$. If I understand correctly, for each $x \in G$, $\text{D}\varphi(x):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ is a linear map, and so $|\text{det}\text{D}\varphi|$ is really a function on $G$. But then how do we compute the right side of $(8.16)$? The left side means $\varphi(\lambda^d)(A):=\lambda^d(\varphi^{-1}(A))$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}^d$.

EDIT: From the comment of WoolierThanThou I believe that the correction interpretation of $(8.16)$ is

$$\lambda_G^d(\varphi^{-1}(A))=\int_A \frac{1}{|\text{det}\text{D}\varphi|\circ \varphi^{-1}} \textrm{d}\lambda_{G'}^d$$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}^d$.

Bauer also mentions that $(8.16)$ is equivalent to the statement

$$\varphi^{-1}(\lambda_{G'}^d)=|\text{det}\text{D}\varphi| \lambda_G^d$$

but why is this so?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're indeed right that the "scalar" on the right hand side is a function. This is what's called a measure with density. If you think of the identity $1\cdot \lambda_G^d(A)=\lambda_G^d(A)=\int_A 1\textrm{d}\lambda_G^d$, then this inspires you to define $f \lambda_G^d(A)=\int_A f\textrm{d}\lambda_G^d$ for general positive functions $f$. The proof itself of the Jacobi transformation theorem (the result above) is a bit involved, though.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou So what $(8.16)$ really means is $\lambda_G^d(\varphi^{-1}(A))=\int_A \frac{1}{|\text{det}\text{D}\varphi|\circ \varphi^{-1}} \textrm{d}\lambda_{G'}^d$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}^d$?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Bauer also mentions that $(8.16)$ is equivalent to $\varphi^{-1}(\lambda_{G'}^d)=|\text{det}\text{D}\varphi| \lambda_G^d$. Why is this so?

Comment: Yes you're correct. Note that to get the equivalent statement, you simply have to note that $(1/|\det D\varphi^{-1}|\circ \varphi)=|\det D\varphi|$ by the chain rule.